# Post and display data on the same page using PHP (MVC) AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm trying to post input data and display it on the same page (view_group.php) using AJAX but I did not understand how it works with MVC, I'm new with MVC if anyone could help me it would be very helpful for me.

**view_group.php**

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var status_content = $('#status_content').val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "view_group.php",
        data: {
          postStatus: postStatus,
          status_content: status_content
        },
        success: function(result) {}
      });
    });
  }); </script>


if(isset($_POST['postStatus'])){ $status->postStatus($group_id); } 
?>

<form class="forms-sample" method="post" id="form-status">
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="status_content" id="status_content" rows="5" placeholder="Share something"></textarea>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
<span id="result"></span>
```

my **controller**

```
function postStatus($group_id){ 
  $status = new ManageGroupsModel(); 
  $status->group_id = $group_id; 
  $status->status_content = $_POST['status_content']; 

  if($status->postStatus() > 0) { 
    $message = "Status posted!"; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first in the ajax url you must set your controller url , then on success result value will be set on your html attribute .

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "your controller url here",
     data: {
      postStatus: postStatus,
      status_content: status_content
     },
     success: function(result) {
       $('#result).text(result);

   }
   });
```

Then on your controller you must echo the result you want to send to your page

```
   function postStatus($group_id){ 
     $status = new ManageGroupsModel(); 
     $status->group_id = $group_id; 
     $status->status_content = $_POST['status_content']; 

       if($status->postStatus() > 0) { 
         $message = "Status posted!"; 
       } 

    echo $status;
    }
```